# Flutter: Image overflow the container

Tags: android, mobile, dart, widget, flutter

I'm making a list of event information in Flutter by using Card for each event. The leading of each card is a related to the event.

I want to make my Card to be rounded corner rectangle, but when I put the image inside the children of Row inside child of Card, the corner of the image is not rounded.

My Card class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SmallEventCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final imageURL;
  final title;
  final time;
  final place;

  SmallEventCard({this.imageURL, this.title, this.time, this.place});

  @override
  _SmallEventCardState createState() => _SmallEventCardState();

}

class _SmallEventCardState extends State<SmallEventCard> {
  bool isFavorite;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    isFavorite = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screen = MediaQuery.of(context).size;


    return Material(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: screen.height / 7,
        child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
                child: Image.network(widget.imageURL,
                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10.0,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(widget.title, 
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
                    Text(widget.time.toString(),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
                    Text(widget.place,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 50.0,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border)),
                  )),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> [image: Preview]

Comment: Good question. was struggling with this for hours. my image height was beyond the card height

Answer (score 30, accepted):

the `Card` widget has it's own clipping behavior so you can just to set the `clipBehavior` property to `Clip.antiAlias` so the content outside the card will be clipped